# AndroidにおいてBinder以外でのプロセス間通信は可能か

Tags: android

[Androidの公式サイト](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)ではプロセス間通信はBinderを使って実現できるという趣旨の記述がありました.
逆に, Binder以外でのプロセス間通信は可能なのでしょうか.

Answer (score 1):

そのドキュメントにもありますが、 `ContentProvider` をIPCに使うことができます。

あるいはアプリ内でHTTP server（またはもっと低レイヤーなTCP server）を立てて他のプロセスと通信するという方法もなくはないですが、安全に運用するのが難しいので最終手段だと思います。